# Why can't a class and function be defined on the same line?

Tags: python, indentation

For some reason, it's impossible to define a method like this:

```
class X:def y():pass #Results in a SyntaxError
```

but you can define a method and the contents on the same line:

```
def y():print("It works!")
```

Why will the second example work but not the first?

Comment: Probably something to do with the second colon. `class Test(object): print('yay')` works :)

Comment: You can also see that `def y(): def z(): pass` fails as well, so it's nothing specific to classes and functions paired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a one-line compound statement, the body must be [a simple statement, or a semicolon-separated list of simple statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-suite):

```
suite         ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | NEWLINE INDENT statement+ DEDENT
statement     ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | compound_stmt
stmt_list     ::=  simple_stmt (";" simple_stmt)* [";"]
```

It cannot be a compound statement. That would open the door to too much confusing and ambiguous syntax. For example,

```
if True: if False: pass
else: print('Which "if" does this "else" go with?')
```